# Game Logic - Change Mesh

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

Searching a little, I discovered that it is possible to change mesh in game logic.

Problem: When the course is over the object it continually changes the mesh as if it were unconfigured.

Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: I test your logic and it works!... i test it with a cube and other objects in a inactive layer, blender version 2.79.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Thanks a lot!
I only understood logic now.

[image]